# In merge_sort algorithm, It works when parameter is double type list, but not when it is int type list

Tags: c, mergesort

I want to sort the `int` type list. but when parameter in merge function is `double` list, it works! but not when it is `int` list...

Here is sorting function. parameter is `int` pointer.

if Changing an `int` list to a `double` list works fine.

ex) `int *a` -> `double *a`

ex) `int *l, *r1` -> `double *l, *r1`

ex) `l = (int *)calloc(n1+1,sizeof(int)), r1 = (int *)calloc(n2+1,sizeof(int))`
-> `l = (double *)calloc(n1+1,sizeof(double)) r1 = (double *)calloc(n2+1,sizeof(double))`

```
void merge(int *a, int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;
    int *l, *r1;
    int i, j, k;

    l = (int *)calloc(n1 + 1, sizeof(int));
    r1 = (int *)calloc(n2 + 1, sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n1;i++)
        l[i] = a[p + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        r1[j] = a[q + 1 + j];

    l[n1] = 10000;
    r1[n2] = 10000;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (k = p; k <= r; k++) {
        if (l[i] <= r1[j]) {
            a[k] = l[i];
            ++i;
        } else {
            a[k] = r1[j];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

here is recursive function. Until the length of the list is `1`

ex) `int *a -> double *a`

```
void merge_sort(int *a, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        merge_sort(a, p, q);
        merge_sort(a, q + 1, r);
        merge(a, p, q, r);
    }
}
```

Create a list of length `10` and put it in the `mergesort` function. Then print the list.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, *a[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;  
    }

    merge_sort(a, 0, 10);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

result is

```
0 0 0 2 5 10 9 9 3 5
```

Comment: In `main`, your array surely should be `int a[10]` (array of 10 ints), not `int *a[10]` (array of 10 pointers to int).

Comment: thank you so~~~ much !! i solve it !! god bless you

Comment: Don't thank me, thank your compiler warnings. (Please switch them on to detect such errors.)

Comment: I'm sorry, can I ask you one more thing? Why was it run when I changed the code from the previous code to the double list?

Comment: My guess is that you are on a system where the size of doubles is the same as the size of pointers, probably 64 bits, but different from the size of ints, usually 32 bits. So it _happened_ to run. Errors like yours invoke what's called "undefined behaviour" in C, which means that what happens isn't predictable. In some cases, what happens looks correct, but isn't. (Unfortunately, C doesn't issue warnings by default, so please switch them on with `-Wall` or `/Wall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- if you wish to change the type of the array element, you must change it everywhere, including in the `main` function and you must also change the `printf` format. Increasing the warning level (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) would prevent silly mistakes.
- the definition of `a` in `main` is incorrect, it should be `int a[10];`, not an array of pointers to `int`.
- you pass the total number of elements to `mergesort()` in `main`: `merge_sort(a, 0, 10);` which means `r` in merge sort should be excluded. The recursive call `merge_sort(a, q + 1, r);` in `mergesort` is then incorrect as `q` should be excluded in `merge_sort(a, p, q);` but included in the second half. Use `merge_sort(a, q, r);` instead.
- you compute the middle of the segment with `int q = (p + r) / 2;`. You may have undefined behavior for large arrays as `q + r` may overflow the range of type `int`. This is a classic bug that can go unnoticed for decades until someone uses the code for a large array. Use `int q = p + (r - p) / 2;` to avoid it.
- the algorithm in `merge` is incorrect: you assume that all values in the arrays are `< 10000`, which may be an invalid assumption. The code should handle all possible values. You should test the index variables to detect the end of the subarrays and handle the remaining values of the other array specifically.
- you do not free the arrays allocated in `merge`, causing memory leaks.
- to make it easier to change the element type, you could use a `typedef`.

Here is a improved version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef USE_DOUBLE
typedef double sorttype;
#else
typedef int sorttype;
#endif

void merge(sorttype *a, int p, int q, int r) {
    // merge subarrays a[p...q] and a[q...r]
    // upper bounds q and r are excluded
    int n1 = q - p;
    int n2 = r - q;
    sorttype *a1, *a2;
    int i, j, k;

    a1 = malloc(n1 * sizeof(*a1));
    a2 = malloc(n2 * sizeof(*a2));

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        a1[i] = a[p + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        a2[j] = a[q + j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (k = p; k < r; k++) {
        if (i < n1 && (j >= n2 || a1[i] <= a2[j])) {
            a[k] = a1[i];
            ++i;
        } else {
            a[k] = a2[j];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    free(a1);
    free(a2);
}

void merge_sort(sorttype *s, int p, int r) {
    if (r - p > 1) {
        int q = p + (r - p) / 2;
        merge_sort(s, p, q);
        merge_sort(s, q, r);
        merge(s, p, q, r);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    sorttype a[10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = 1 + rand() % 10;
    }

    merge_sort(a, 0, 10);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
#ifdef USE_DOUBLE
        printf("%g ", a[i]);
#else
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
#endif
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output for `int`:

```
1 3 4 4 5 8 9 9 10 10
```

Output for `double`:

```
1 3 4 4 5 8 9 9 10 10
```

Notice how the random numbers are identical although the program was recompiled and re-run... You should use `srand(clock())` to try and get a different pseudo-random sequence.

Note also that allocating `a2` to make a copy of the right subarray is not required because the merge operation never overwrites elements from the right half that have not already been copied.

Furthermore, you should test for allocation failure and report it.

Here is an improved version of `merge`:

```c
void merge(sorttype *a, int p, int q, int r) {
    // merge subarrays a[p...q] and a[q...r]
    // upper bounds q and r are excluded
    int n1 = q - p;
    int n2 = r - q;
    sorttype *a1;
    int i, j, k;

    a1 = malloc(n1 * sizeof(*a1));
    if (a1 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        a1[i] = a[p + i];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (k = p; i < n1 && k < r; k++) {
        if (j >= n2 || a1[i] <= a[q + j]) {
            a[k] = a1[i];
            ++i;
        } else {
            a[k] = a[q + j];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    free(a1);
}
```

Comment: overflow with `int q = (p + r) / 2`. In the case of a 32 bit environment, overflow would be rare. At best, a program might be able to allocate 2GB or 3GB of memory, and a typical merge sort would use 2 arrays, with a max size of 1GB or 1.5GB each,  which could only overflow if sorting characters (8 bit values). For 64 bit environment, long long or int64_t or if you're willing to deal with unsigned indexes, size_t will work for both 32 and 64 bit environments. Still the overhead of using q = (p+(r-p)/2) is small, and it would prevent working code from failing later on in those rare cases.